# Does a good tool exist to work with Google Cloud Platform Deployment manager files?

Tags: google-deployment-manager

To edit configuration files that can be used by GCP Deployment manager I found no tools providing auto completion.

As the article [Creating a Basic Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-basic-configuration) suggests, a human being should manually search for valid values using

```
gcloud deployment-manager types list
```

and check the syntax by a trial and error process.

Behind the scenes I imagine that the tool should call commands such as:

```
gcloud deployment-manager types list
```

so it shouldn't be that hard but even the Google Cloud official plugin for IntelliJ doesn't do that.

What is a tool that provides auto completion for such file types?

Answer (score 0):

As this is currently not possible with IntelliJ Cloud Code, you may want to suggest this to the development team through this [Github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues) as a feature request.

Comment: Thank you Gustavo, done: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues/2757